# Vector not containing the right data it seems

Tags: java

Here is the list function, as you can see it's printing the content of newEntry before being added to the vector dataList.

```
public static Vector<entry> list()
{
    entry newEntry = new entry();
    Vector<entry> dataList = new Vector<entry>();
    String[] splitLine;
    String currentLine;
    String formattedString = "";

    BufferedReader in;
    try
    {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("data.txt")));
        while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            newEntry = new entry();
            splitLine = currentLine.split(" ");
            newEntry.record = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[0]);
            newEntry.fName = splitLine[1];
            newEntry.lName = splitLine[2];
            newEntry.phoneNumber = splitLine[3];
            dataList.add(newEntry);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(dataList.elementAt(i).record + dataList.elementAt(i).fName + dataList.elementAt(i).lName + dataList.elementAt(i).phoneNumber);
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

Here is the part where I'm having an issue, it's taking whatever list() is returned (above) and forming it into a new vector and will be printed off.  However, it's only printing the last value for some reason...

```
if ((params[0].toLowerCase()).equals("list"))
{
    Vector<entry> printList = new Vector<entry>(list());
    for (int i = 0; i < printList.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(printList.elementAt(i).record + printList.elementAt(i).fName + printList.elementAt(i).lName + printList.elementAt(i).phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

This is the output I get when 3 (the first 3 shown below) is added to the dataList in the list function.

> 1000 John Carter 1731371313
>   1001 Abe Lincoln 9173913143
>   1002 William Tell 794174141
>   1002 William Tell 794174141
>   1002 William Tell 794174141
>   1002 William Tell 794174141

Does anyone know what may be wrong?

Comment: Start by using `ArrayList`. `Vector` is an old implementation that should almost never be used because better alternatives exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you insert the same object into the container three times. You should construct a new object before inserting it.

```
splitLine = currentLine.split(" ");
newEntry = new entry();
newEntry.record = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[0]);
newEntry.fName = splitLine[1];
newEntry.lName = splitLine[2];
newEntry.phoneNumber = splitLine[3];
System.out.println(newEntry.record + newEntry.fName + newEntry.lName + newEntry.phoneNumber);
dataList.add(newEntry);
```

It's a good thing you posted your full code, because you have an additional error :

```
public static class entry
{
        public static int record;
        public static String fName;
        public static String lName;
        public static String phoneNumber;
}
```

Declaring the members of the `entry` class as static causes them to be shared by all instances of your class. That's why all instances of the `entry` class hold the values of the last entry. Remove the `static` keyword from all the members and everything will work.

Comment: I've tried this, I'm still getting the same result.  Plus if it's inserting the same object the same time, why is it doing the last one (1002 William Tell somenumber)?  Wouldn't it just do the first one?

Comment: Because on each iteration of the loop you are modifying the members of the same object, so after you are done, that object contains the data you entered in the last iteration.

Comment: Right so in the first iteration, the "1000 John Carter 1731371313" entry (first line in file) is added to dataList.  That should be in index 0 of dataList, so then I go back to the top, created a new newEntry entry and then it should put in "1001 Abe Lincoln 9173913143" entry, right? It'd be at index 1, then William Tell will come in at 2.  However, this isn't the case for me, it's still all William Tell.  I even printed the dataList before returning it out of the function.  I updated the list function above.

Comment: If you create a new entry object on each iteration of the loop, your vector should contain three different objects with the values you expect. If you're still getting the last entry three times, that means you are not creating a new object in each iteration.

Comment: Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/uNbabSr9   And here is my output: http://i.imgur.com/WQFkMvE.png

Comment: That fixed it.  I now need to go re-read about static types because I don't exactly know what it's for.

Answer (score 3):

You keep overwriting newEntry. 
This line needs to be in the loop:

```
entry newEntry = new entry();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
entry newEntry = new entry();
```

This is the only place where you declare an `entry` object.  As such, when you do this:

```
newEntry.record = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[0]);
newEntry.fName = splitLine[1];
newEntry.lName = splitLine[2];
newEntry.phoneNumber = splitLine[3];
```

You're just changing the values in the current object.

A better approach might look like this:

```
while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    newEntry = new entry();
    splitLine = currentLine.split(" ");
    newEntry.record = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[0]);
    newEntry.fName = splitLine[1];
    newEntry.lName = splitLine[2];
    newEntry.phoneNumber = splitLine[3];
    dataList.add(newEntry);
}
```

---

But if I were doing it, I'd write a constructor for the `entry` class that just takes 4 strings, and initializes `record`, `fName`, `lName`, and `phoneNumber` based on these 4 strings (you can `parseInt` within the constructor).

For example:

```
public entry(string rec, string first, string last, string phone) {
    record = Integer.parseInt(rec);
    fName = first;
    lName = last;
    phoneNumber = phone;
}
```

So then in your loop where you're taking the data in, you can simply do this:

```
while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    splitLine = currentLine.split(" ");
    newEntry = new entry(splitLine[0], splitLine[1], splitLine[2], splitLine[3]);
    dataList.add(newEntry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using the same instance of entry in your while. You are making the instance before your while. Each file's row in your code is one entry, right? So, making a new inatance for each line.

```
while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null){

    newEntry = new entry();

    //do whatever you want

    dataList.add(newEntry);

}
```